# Mysql consume lots of space in ubuntu 20.4

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, amazon-ec2

I need help regarding my application deployed in ec2 instance using T3 medium and Ubuntu 20. My problem is, I encountered a server error twice, it happens 3 months after each error. Prior to server error, I noticed I am greeted this message  `99.5% of **GB` once  I log into the terminal console. The first server error happened three months ago I used a t2 tier, so without hesitation, I upgraded it to much bigger t3 with 30GB disk capacity. Now the error happens again, after 3 months or more. Again I noticed the `99.5% of 29.02GB` and after few days I encountere the 500 error. I tried to investigate, I found out that the `var/lib/mysql` folder consumed a lot of space!. I am just wondering because my application is under in development, so data stored in mysql are minimal. So I tried to dump the db and inspect the stored data, its only less 1GB, and i have only 1 database in my ec2 instance.

Running `sudo du lib -h`, it shows `23G var/lib/mysql`, I tried to restart the mysql server, the error is gone, but still the size doesnt change.

So my question is, why the folder lib/mysql consumed lots of space but in fact the actual data stored in database is just below 1 gb? So clearly, restarting mysql everytime an error encountered is just a temporary solution, and increasing the database space is not also the solution. Do you have idea what causes this and how to prevent this?. My application is still in development and I would like to solve the issue before deployment to production.

Many thanks.

Comment: what's the result of `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_file_per_table';` on your MySQL instance?

Comment: @mforsetti it shows `ON` in its value

Comment: so it's not `ibdata*` bloat. it could be either MySQL logs or binary logs. What's the result of `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'log_%';` and `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'slow_query_log%';` on your MySQL instance?

Comment: Running `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'slow_query_log%';`, it shows  slow_query_log      | OFF

Comment: Running `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'log_%';`, it shows log_bin                                | ON , log_bin_basename | /var/lib/mysql/binlog, log_error_verbosity | 2

Comment: log_slave_updates| ON, log_statements_unsafe_for_binlog | ON

Comment: alright you got binlog on, try running `SHOW BINARY LOGS` and see how many binary logs you have.

Comment: Oh my God,  binlog.000282 | 106260830 | No     and there are lots of them(236 rows). Is this the reason ?How to prevent this ?

Comment: @mforsetti, thanks for the help. I solve the issue.Maybe you can convert your comments to answer

Comment: What is the name of the largest file?